# Javascript fixed nav on scroll - What's the difference here?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a fixed nav when you scroll.

I've got it working but I'm confused as to why my first version doesn't work properly. It works on the way down but on the way up stays stuck to the top of the window.

Version 1 (Not working properly)

https://jsfiddle.net/9dqabdj5/2/

```
// Get nav
var nav = document.querySelector('nav');

function navOffsetTop() {
    if(window.scrollY >= nav.offsetTop) {
        document.body.style.paddingTop = nav.offsetHeight + 'px';
        document.body.classList.add('fixed-top');
    } else {
        document.body.style.paddingTop = 0;
        document.body.classList.remove('fixed-top');
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', navOffsetTop);
```

Version 2 (Working) - The only difference is 'offset.Top' is in a variable.

https://jsfiddle.net/9kdy0s9n/

```
// Get nav
var nav = document.querySelector('nav');
var navTop = nav.offsetTop;

function navOffsetTop() {
    if(window.scrollY >= navTop) {
        document.body.style.paddingTop = nav.offsetHeight + 'px';
        document.body.classList.add('fixed-top');
    } else {
        document.body.style.paddingTop = 0;
        document.body.classList.remove('fixed-top');
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', navOffsetTop);
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you not call it inside the if statement?

Comment: sorry, jumped the gun there

Comment: I think I get it now...

on the not working one it only starts calculating after the if statement instead of when you begin scrolling from the top so the calculation is wrong right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Version 1** `offsetTop` becomes 0 and stays 0 after the menu has been fixed on the way down. So `if(window.scrollY >= nav.offsetTop)` effectively always comes out to `true` and keeps `fixed-top` on the `nav` element continuously.

In **Version 2**, `navTop` is evaluated once (starts at ~195px in the jsfiddle) and stays that value throughout the whole lifecycle. This allows the `else` to execute because `window.scrollY` can eventually be less than `navTop` when scrolled back up high enough.

Try adding `console.log(nav.offsetTop)` within `navOffsetTop()` and see the `offsetTop` value at different scroll distances.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for your reply.

I understand the top one wasn't working it's just that I didn't understand why the one in the if statement didn't as it's essentially the same code.